# Concatenating Multiple MySQL Columns and Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on MySQL and am having trouble with combining data. I don't want to do this in the external layer.

Basically, I have an **item** table. The table structure looks like this:

```
=========================
 id    item_name   stock
=========================
 1     Soap        100
 2     Plate       89
 3     Scissor     72
=========================
```

I know, I could use MySQL *`GROUP_CONCAT()`* function:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item_name SEPARATOR  ', ') AS items FROM item WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

With results:

```
======================
 items
======================
 Soap, Plate, Scissor
======================
```

But, the desired result is:

```
 Soap (100), Plate (89), Scissor (72)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, just constructing the each element from the `item_name` and `stock` before the aggregation:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item_name, ' (', stock, ')' SEPARATOR  ', ') AS items
FROM item
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

A little known fact is that `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes multiple arguments.  You could also write this as:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(item_name, ' (', stock, ')') SEPARATOR  ', '
                   ) AS items
FROM item
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`:

`select item_name, count(*) from item group by item_name`

You should understand `Aggregate` statements (the `count(*)`) and grouping in SQL:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp